# How to define the path of agent8531, coordinator8529, dbserver8530, setup.json files when clustering arangoDB

Tags: cluster-computing, arangodb

When clustering 3 ArangoDB hosts referenced by https://github.com/arangodb-helper/arangodb

I found that 4 files/directories(**agent8531**, **coordinator8529**, **dbserver8530**, **setup.json**) are created on current path when execute clustering.

How to define the path of those files/directories explicitly?